# Call method with method name (in typescript)

Tags: typescript

I want to call a method using its name, but it doesn't work because I get a typescript error.

`A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.`

Below is the code written to simplify this situation.

```
const methods = {
  hello: (foo: number) => {
    console.log(foo);
  },
  world: (foo: string, bar: boolean, baz: number) => {
    console.log(foo, bar, baz);
  },
};

type METHODS = typeof methods;

export const callMethod = <METHOD_NAME extends keyof METHODS>(
  name: METHOD_NAME,
  args: Parameters<METHODS[METHOD_NAME]>
) => {
  return methods[name](...args);
};
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUygCxAEwjAvDA3gKBhmQQBtSQAuGACgDMQqYwBXOAIwQCcBKbAPjyEiMUJBCkEAOgoBzeox4BuYQF8ANMIDuILqTTUFTaFwCWYWepjsAhl2rtGkm2Cu2AXtVYdufLIIIRUXAICWk5Izc7KPdlNU1VFXwoAE8ABwQYAFkAUQAVAAkAeQARAGVsGFSMkDp4JFQMJIQADzTdWDFoURtyLIb0SoAeXMLSgH0AOQBBXJhWqAQwDBgAawQU2uz84vL+GmEwG0RqUd2p2ZzNIjS7Y4hqAAU7xEWuCBGd0rKAbTOJma5AC6-HwfgCwi4SBYXDA9RQ6AgPyOiCBNCkGNuXHucUSQA)

Can I get some help to solve this problem?

Comment: Try this ``return (methods[name] as Function)(...params);``

Comment: Are you just trying to suppress the error, or get the compiler to "understand" your logic?  If it's the latter, you can use the refactoring as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), and as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQJV7N).  If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Oh, I want to the latter!

Comment: @jcalz Is there any possible way without `const methods: {...}  = _methods`?

Comment: Not that I know of; why does it matter?  I hope it doesn't matter much because I'm in the middle of writing up an answer based on the apparent positive response from your previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TypeScript type checker doesn't really know how to reason much about [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  In your example, `Parameters<Methods[K]>` is such a type, because [the `Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) is implemented as a conditional type, and `K` (you're calling it `METHOD_NAME`) is a generic type parameter.  This is a design limitation of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#47615](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47615).

The most expedient approach is to just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the error:

```
export const callMethod = <K extends keyof Methods>(
  name: K,
  params: Parameters<Methods[K]>
) => {
  return (methods[name] as (...args: any) => void)(...params);
                     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

This is basically you telling the compiler not to worry about type checking the code because you've taken responsibility for it.

---

If you want the compiler to actually perform type checking accurately, you'll need to refactor.  The recommended approach in situations like this is to avoid conditional types entirely, and instead write the operations in terms of some basic key-value type and generic [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into either that type or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type.  This is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

For your code, we want to make the basic key-value type a mapping from the method name to its argument list, like:

```
type MethodArgs = {
    hello: [foo: number];
    world: [foo: string, bar: boolean, baz: number];
}
```

And then we define `methods` in terms of that, like

```
const methods: { [K in keyof MethodArgs]: (...args: MethodArgs[K]) => void } = {
  hello: (foo) => { console.log(foo); },
  world: (foo, bar, baz) => { console.log(foo, bar, baz); },
}
```

And then `callMethod()` can be rewritten as follows with no compiler error:

```
export const callMethod = <K extends keyof MethodArgs>(
  name: K,
  params: MethodArgs[K]
) => {
  return methods[name](...params);
};
```

Note that if you inspect it, the type of `methods` is equivalent to what it was before.  But the difference is that this version is explicitly written as a mapped type over `MethodArgs`, which allows the compiler to "understand" what you're doing with `methods[name](...params)`.

---

That's the basic technique, although in your case you already had `methods` defined.  If you want, you can start with such a definition (but rename it first):

```
const _methods = {
  hello: (foo: number) => {
    console.log(foo);
  },
  world: (foo: string, bar: boolean, baz: number) => {
    console.log(foo, bar, baz);
  },
};
```

And then compute `MethodArgs` in terms of it, like this:

```
type Methods = typeof _methods;
type MethodArgs = { [K in keyof Methods]: Parameters<Methods[K]> }
```

And finally assign the renamed value to the desired variable of the desired type:

```
const methods: { [K in keyof MethodArgs]: (...args: MethodArgs[K]) => void } = _methods;
```

And again, this looks like a bunch of type and value shuffling that shouldn't have an effect.  But the effect is precisely that the compiler follows the logic when things are written this way.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-2NCw+qp+qYoTAYmZ4JDfJC+TbbXYfJg-B5PGivd6hpjfP6ejhcjoFzEJpMprY7doZmMYrMiVF6dGYhuxqBF6UEomemYhqZQMokAD0ACpS+lqEIq4sa2n6wXG1Bm6S212hJ2MT3kn3plZ4-Zhfx3MrpQm5boFUrTGZPR6SJrXOeJM7XTa0tob4730aXSNAoH3VT1wyQCcx29JYBiGb9RngcYeAzGYFhglY1mYWt0wrI4Tmec4nyQckwA7FcuyLAEbXsMFsAhKE+W7OEfg3EioFVL0CCsIA)